# Can't import tkinter in python2 on manjaro linux

Tags: python, manjaro, python3

I installed tk-8.6.8.3 using pacman and I can import tkinter in python3 but not in python2. There doesn't seem to be a separate package for tkinter for python2 in the repositories. How do I get tkinter to work in python2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you install the tk package with pacman I believe it should be available to both python3 and python2 in Manjaro and Arch.

Try `import Tkinter` in the python2 interpreter (With the capitalized 'T').

Comment: Damn! So it's Tkinter in python2 and tkinter in python3! I am trying to run UCSF-Chimera and it's not able to import Tkinter. It says, 

`File "/opt/UCSF/Chimera64-1.12/share/chimera/replyobj.py", line 24, in <module>
    import Tkinter
  File "/opt/UCSF/Chimera64-1.12/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 39, in <module>
    import _tkinter # If this fails your Python may not be configured for Tk
ImportError: /usr/lib64/libfontconfig.so.1: undefined symbol: FT_Done_MM_Var `
 I know I'm straying away from the original question, but any ideas how this can be fixed? Any configuration?

Comment: Did you build UCSF-Chimera from the AUR [package](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/ucsf-chimera/)?

Comment: Nope. I downloaded the executable from their website to build it. The AUR package is outdated (2013).

Comment: Even in Pymol (that runs fine and I'm using it currently as a replacement), the PDB plugin requires Tkinter and it doesn't work. It says `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tkSimpleDialog'`. This leads me to believe it is a Tkinter problem.

Comment: Solved it using this: https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/ucsf-chimera/?comments=all